# How to pass code-generated controls to another method

Tags: c#, methods

and thanks to any who'll take the time to look / answer this question.

I'm actually having difficulties to pass the controls I add in this method :

```
private void btn_AddAuthor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button cbtn_CreateNewAuthor = new Button();
            Label clbl_AuthorName = new Label();
            TextBox ctb_AuthorName = new TextBox();
            Label clbl_AuthorLastName = new Label();
            TextBox ctb_AuthorLastName = new TextBox();

            // The first name
            clbl_AuthorName.Text = "Prénom de l'Auteur :";
            clbl_AuthorName.AutoSize = false;
            clbl_AuthorName.Height = 20;
            clbl_AuthorName.Width = 100;
            flp_AddNewThings.Controls.Add(clbl_AuthorName);
            flp_AddNewThings.Controls.Add(ctb_AuthorName);
            flp_AddNewThings.SetFlowBreak(ctb_AuthorName, true);

            // the Last Name
            clbl_AuthorLastName.Text = "Nom de l'Auteur";
            clbl_AuthorName.AutoSize = false;
            clbl_AuthorName.Height = 20;
            clbl_AuthorName.Width = 100;
            flp_AddNewThings.Controls.Add(clbl_AuthorLastName);
            flp_AddNewThings.Controls.Add(ctb_AuthorLastName);
            flp_AddNewThings.SetFlowBreak(ctb_AuthorLastName, true);

            //The Button
            cbtn_CreateNewAuthor.Text = "Nouvel Auteur";
            cbtn_CreateNewAuthor.Click += new System.EventHandler(cbtn_CreateNewAuthor_Click);
            flp_AddNewThings.Controls.Add(cbtn_CreateNewAuthor);

        }
```

to this other one where I'd like to use what they contains in order the Author object:

```
private void cbtn_CreateNewAuthor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new ProgramContext())
    {

    }
}
```

Of course, if you have a better way to handle that, I would be more than glad to consider it !

Thanks to James, I managed to work the second class out, I'm putting it there since the SingleOrDefault is absent from the flp_AddNewThings.Controls :

```
private void cbtn_CreateNewAuthor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new ProgramContext())
    {
        // First we create a list of the flow layout panel controls and add the controls to it
        List<Control> AllControls = new List<Control>();
        foreach (Control c in flp_AddNewThings.Controls)
        {
            AllControls.Add(c);
        }

        // Then we take the controls we need
        var txtFirstName = AllControls.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Tag == "txtFirstName");
        var txtLastName = AllControls.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Tag == "txtLastName");

        // if the two above arent null, we go on :
        var author = new Author();
        if (txtFirstName != null && txtLastName != null)
        {
            // We make sure there's actually a name and last name entered
            if (txtFirstName.Text == "" && txtLastName.Text == "")
            {
                author.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
                author.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
            }
            else // else we make the person aware it's needed
            {
                if (txtFirstName.Text == "") flp_AddNewThings.Controls.Add(new Label{ Text = "Vous devez ajouter un Prénom"});
                if (txtLastName.Text == "") flp_AddNewThings.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Vous devez ajouter un Nom de Famille" });
            }

            // On vérifie que l'auteur n'est pas dans la bd

            var AutorOk = db.Authors.Any(x => x.LastName == author.LastName && x.FirstName == author.FirstName);
            if (AutorOk)
            {
                db.Authors.Add(author);
                db.SaveChanges();

                // Display all Authors from the database 
                var query = from b in db.Authors
                            orderby b.DisplayName
                            select b;

                LogBox.Text = "Auteurs Connus : \n";
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    LogBox.AppendText(item.DisplayName + "\n");
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you need to make reference to them again in another method, can you not simply make them class member variables?

Comment: Hum, I'm relatively new to programming so the idea didn't hit me. I thought that class member would stay the whole time in memory, while I only need them temporaly...

Comment: What is **flp_AddNewThings** ? I mean which control ??

Comment: It's a Flow Layout Panel.

Comment: Apart from **Tag** property suggested by James, you can also use **GetEnumerator()** method like this - **flowlayoutpanel.Controls.GetEnumerator()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can only add one author at a time, then a class reference would be the simplest approach

```
private TextBox ctb_AuthorName;
private TextBox ctb_AuthorLastName;
...
this.ctb_AuthorName = new TextBox();
this.ctb_AuthorLastName = new TextBox();
...

private void cbtn_CreateNewAuthor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new ProgramContext())
    { 
        var author = new Author(ctb_AuthorName.Text, ctb_AuthorLastName.Text);
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could look up the control from the `Controls` collection in your `FlowLayoutPanel`. You can use the `Tag` property to give each of your controls a unique identifier e.g.

```
TextBox ctb_AuthorName = new TextBox();
ctb_AuthorName.Tag = "txtForename";
TextBox ctb_AuthorLastName = new TextBox();
ctb_AuthorLastName.Tag = "txtSurname";
```

Then in your `cbtn_CreateNewAuthor_Click` event, use those tags to lookup the control

```
private Control FindControlByTag(Control.ControlCollection controls, string tag)
{
    Control result = null;
    foreach (var ctrl in controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.Tag == tag)
        {
            result = ctrl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private void cbtn_CreateNewAuthor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new ProgramContext())
    {
        var txtForename = FindControlByTag(flp_AddNewThings.Controls, "txtForename");
        var txtSurname = FindControlByTag(flp_AddNewThings.Controls, "txtSurname");
        if (txtForename != null && txtSurname != null)
        {
            var author = new Author(txtForename.Text, txtSurname.Text);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You could take this a step further and make the `FindControlByTag` method an extension of `ControlCollection`

```
public static class ControlCollectionExt
{
    public static Control FindByTag(this Control.ControlCollection controls, string tag)
    {
        Control result = null;
        foreach (var ctrl in controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.Tag == tag)
            {
                result = ctrl;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This would reduce your code to

```
var txtForename = flp_AddNewThings.Controls.FindByTag("txtForename");
var txtSurname = flp_AddNewThings.Controls.FindByTag("txtSurname");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer ! And it's good to see how the tag can be used too !

Comment: However, there's no SingleOrDefault on the flp_AddNewThings.Controls, so I add my own way of doing it upside on the solution.

Comment: @Ukyuu ah that was my mistake, [ControlCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't support `IEnumerable<T>` therefore won't support the LINQ extensions. Alternatively, the `ControlCollection` class has it's own [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) method but this checks the `Name` property, not the `Tag`. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Ukyuu see update. I seen your code and that will work, however, seems silly to create an entirely new list just for the LINQ extensions, a `foreach` loop will be just as quick.

Comment: I"m trying your static class thingy, but seems like I miss a using of some sort, and I don't see how to make it work...

Comment: using this : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/5552/winform to see if I can actually figure out why it doesn't compile

Comment: @Ukyuu the "*static class thingy*" is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx), you just need to add a using to the namespace of the class your extension method is sitting in. For example, if you added the `ControlCollectionEtc` class to a namespace like `MyApp.Helpers` then you would need to add `using MyApp.Helpers` to the top of the class in which you are going to use the extension - otherwise the extension is not applied.

Comment: Sorry for how I called it. Fact is, it shows build error. It simply just don't compile and I don't know why.

Comment: @Ukyuu does the build error not give you any indication on what's going wrong?

Comment: It asks for a ";" after control insiede the "for" loop.

Comment: @Ukyuu ah, typo. `for` should be `foreach`.

Comment: Okay, now it's completely working, also changed "this ControlCollection" for this "Control.ControlCollection" else it shows an error too

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(Control c in flp_AddNewThings.Controls)
{
    if(c is TextBox)
    {
        db.Save(c.Text);
    }
    ...
}
```